# Selecting Child elements css

Tags: html, css

hey so im doing something for a Webdesign class I'm taking. I'm trying to select these `<h2>`'s inside element `<divclass=left>` but It's not working for me.

[image]

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    color: white;
    justify-content: space-between;
   

}

.left h2{margin-left: 20px}

.right{
 }

body{padding:0; margin: 0}


 
.boxs {
    display: flex
}

.boxs>* {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    border: black solid 2px;
    box-sizing: border
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <nav>
       <div class=left></div> <i class="fas fa-ad"></i>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <h2>Browser</h2>
      <h2>Download</h2>
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
    </nav>
    <div class="right"><h2>Sign-in</h2></div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Which elements are you trying to select and what results are you looking for?

Comment: you have no element with `boxs` class

Answer (score 1):

Your div with the class `left` is not wrapping anything. Your HTML should look like this if you want the CSS `.left h2` to work.

```css
.left h2{margin-left: 20px}
```

```html
<nav>
  <nav>
    <div class="left"> <i class="fas fa-ad"></i>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <h2>Browser</h2>
      <h2>Download</h2>
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>Sign-in</h2>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to select h2 elements:

```
nav h2 {
  color: red;
}
```